# NVDA is not reading the button which is inside the Material UI Popover when it is being focused through "Tab" key

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui, nvda

I have a single Button(lets say edit button) inside Material-UI Popover and I'm using "NVDA" screen reader. I'm trying to access the edit button through "Tab" key. The button is being focused but it is not reading in NVDA reader. When I click the "down arrow" key then only it's reading. How to get it read by NVDA when the "edit" button is focused by "Tab" key.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code:

```
<Popover
    id={"yoo"}
    open={open}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "center"
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "center"
    }}
  >
    <Button onClick={() => console.log("hello")} role="button" tabIndex={0}>
      <Typography className={classes.typography}>edit</Typography>
    </Button>
  </Popover>
```

full code in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-25khy3?file=/demo.tsx

and the screenshot for reference
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer but I spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out.  Usually when you can <kbd>tab</kbd> to an element but it's not announced, that's because the element has been removed from the [accessibility tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessibility-tree) but the element itself can still receive keyboard focus. This often happens if an ancestor element accidentally sets `aria-hidden="true"`.

```html
<div aria-hidden="true">
  <div>
    <button>foo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

A `<button>` element is natively keyboard focusable so I can always <kbd>tab</kbd> to it. But since the parent container has `aria-hidden="true"`, all descendents will be hidden from assistive technology (such as NVDA) and nothing will be announced when it receives focus. [ARIA attributes do not affect any kind of behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#nativesemantics). They're strictly for conveying information to assistive technology. So setting aria-hidden does not cause an element to not be keyboard focusable.

In the case of the popover element, aria-hidden **is** being set on the background elements but those elements are **siblings** of the popover content so aria-hidden should not affect the contents of the popover.

I modified the example in the OP to have a couple buttons before the popover button and I added a few buttons inside the popover contents.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The basic HTML structure when the popover contents are displayed is:

```html
<div id="root" aria-hidden="true">
  <div>
    <button>foo</button>
    <button>bar</button>
    <button aria-describedby="simple-popover">
      <span class="MuiButton-label">Open Popover</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div role="presentation" class="MuiPopover-root">
  <div aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" data-test="sentinelStart"></div>
  <div tabindex="-1">
    <button>foo2</button>
    <button>bar2</button>
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root...">
      <span class="MuiButton-label">
        <p class="MuiTypography-root makeStyles-typography-1 MuiTypography-body1">edit</p>
      </span>
    </button>
    <button>baz</button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" data-test="sentinelEnd"></div>
</div>
```

(I removed some elements to make the code simpler)

The `<div>` with `id="root"` is a **sibling** of the `<div>` with `role="presentation"` (which is the popover contents) so the `aria-hidden="true"` set on the root does not affect the `<div>` that contains the popover buttons.

(Note that there is a `<div>` with `aria-hidden="true"` inside the popover contents but it's not a parent container of anything.)

Anyway, when I have multiple interactive elements inside the popover contents, tabbing to each one **is** announced by NVDA **except** the first time I <kbd>tab</kbd> to the first element (foo2). But if I tab to the other elements and then back to foo2, it's announced.

If I **only** have one interactive element in the popover contents, then it's never announced because there isn't a second element to tab to.

When I inspect the accessibility tree, the first element is not exposed to the accessibility tree, thus it won't be announced. But if I have multiple elements, then the first element **is** exposed. There must be some funky javascript happening in the background to cause the first element to be hidden.

I know none of this answers your question but I wanted to post the results of my testing and couldn't fit all this in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for trying it out mate. I noticed it too that when you have only one button in the popover, it's not reading in NVDA. The first button is reading when you have multiple buttons. I don't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: The reason is because the element is removed from the accessibility tree.  Now, **why** it's removed from the a11y tree was extremely puzzling. There must be something funky going on in the JS because I could not track it down.